# How to style v-layout v-select with condition?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

Here is my code:

```
<v-layout style="width: 230px; height: 25px; padding-left: 0">
   <v-select
      :items="regionsNames"
      v-model="defRegionName"
      @change="changeRegion(defRegionName)"
      dense
      solo
   ></v-select>
</v-layout>
```

Is there any opportunity to style it with condition? `regionsNames` is array, not object (and it has to be array)

Something like:
`:style="[index === productsGamersBigIndex ? {'width': '750px'} : '']"`

Comment: What do you mean by "style it with condition" ? You want to add a class depending of a boolean or is it something else ?

Comment: Yeah, something like `:style="[index === productsGamersBigIndex ? {'width': '750px'} : '']"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try template strings:

```html
<v-layout :style="`width: 230px; height: 25px; padding-left: {(index > 0 ? '20px' : 0)}`">
```

You can also bind an object:

```html
<v-layout
  :style="{
    width: '230px',
    height: '25px',
    'padding-left': index > 0 ? '20px' : 0,
  }"
>
```

You can even use a data object or computed property from the component